# Generate new order of numbers from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm currently trying to generate a new order of numbers from a current array with numbers from 1 - 10.

For example, I have arrary like this:

```
data = [
    {
        0: 1,
        1: 2,
        2: 3,
        3: 4,
        4: 5,
        5: 6
    },
    {
        0: 1,
        1: 2,
        2: 3,
        3: 4,
        4: 5,
        5: 8
    }
]
```

And i'm trying to generate a new order from this array from numbers from 1 - 10.

For example:
I want it to generate a new order like this:

```
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 3,
    3: 4,
    4: 5,
    5: 7 (The new number)
```

Where it checks the order of the array, and make a new order with numbers from 1 - 10

Comment: You mean you want to combine the two objects in the array where every number is the average of the values with the same keys? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes that's correct! I'm kinda lost myself... So i'm not sure how to approach it

Comment: What should happen whenever your average is not a whole number? For example the average is `5.25`?

Comment: Good question, maybe a false feedback

Comment: *maybe a false feedback* could you clarify? What would that look like? How about rounding the number to the nearest whole number?

Comment: Nearest whole number would be better yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to create an object with the total values. We can accomplish this by looping over each object in the array and add each value to a new object. For this we can use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the `data` array.

After that loop over the object with the totals and divide each value with the amount of objects that are present in the `data` array.

Use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to round each value to the nearest whole number.

```js
const data = [{
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 3,
    3: 4,
    4: 5,
    5: 6
  },
  {
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 3,
    3: 4,
    4: 5,
    5: 8
  }
];

function getDataTotal(data) {
  const totalObject = data.reduce((total, curObj) => {
    for (const key of Object.keys(curObj)) {
      total[key] = total[key] 
        ? total[key] + curObj[key] 
        : curObj[key];
    }

    return total;
  }, {});

  const averageObject = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(totalObject)) {
    averageObject[key] = Math.round(value / data.length);
  }

  return averageObject;
}

const averageObject = getDataTotal(data);
console.log(averageObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same keys on both objects.

```
const data = [
  {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6},
  {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 8},
]

getAverageValueOfMappingElements() {
      const keys = Object.keys(data[0])

      return [...keys].map(key => {
        return (data[0][key] + data[1][key]) / 2
      })
    }
```